# Is it possible to upload a video file to IBM Cloud Functions / OpenWhisk function and encode it?

Tags: ibm-cloud, serverless-framework, openwhisk, serverless-architecture

We are developing a video streaming platform. In that we want to encode video into H.264 format after uploading it.

We decided to use IBM Cloud Functions / OpenWhisk to encode the video, but having some doubts. Is it possible to upload a video file to IBM Cloud Functions / OpenWhisk and encode it? Is it supported, how can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that should be possible.

I recommend checking out this ["Dark Vision" app](http://openwhisk-darkvision.mybluemix.net/) using IBM Cloud Functions. You can upload videos which then are split into frames, the frames processed with Visual Recognition. The [source code for Dark Vision is available on GitHub](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/openwhisk-darkvisionapp).

In addition you should go over the documented [IBM Cloud Functions system limits](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/openwhisk/openwhisk_reference.html#openwhisk_syslimits) to see if they match your requirements.